# I setup psql and pgadmin on my mac. I can create database and tables on both but they don't seem to connect

Tags: database, postgresql, macos, psql, pgadmin

I have psql installed on my mac. The databases on psql and pgadmin are different and I can't seem to connect them to each other. I would like to be able to create a database and table in psql and have it also available in pgadmin but unable to so far. I tried google and stackoverflow with no success.

The psql shell on my mac is version is 10.4
The pgadmin gui on my mac is version 3.0

Is there any way that these two can be connected to each other so I can manipulate database with either?

I've created a database on pgadmin using the GUI and/or through jupyter notebook via sqlalchemy but it doesn't show up on psql. I've created a database and table on psql but it doesn't show up on pgadmin.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Tried to google to see if I can connect to pgadmin from psql but couldn't find anything.

Let me know what I'm doing wrong and how I can connect those two. Thanks

Comment: It's kind of hard to know what you're doing wrong without knowing exactly what you are doing.   Run these queries in both contexts, `select inet_server_addr(),inet_server_port(),current_database();` and also `SHOW data_directory;` any differences in the results could be a clue

Comment: Ok so I was able to connect to the pgadmin database using format ' \c "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=database password=password" '. Now I'm able to see the database in my psql. I typed all the commands you suggested in both terminals(one in my original database I start and the other one connected to pgadmin). One diff is my initial psql directory is '/Users/Ergosphere/PostgreSQL/data/pg10' while the pgadmin directory is '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data'. Is there a way for psql to start directly in the pgadmin database or do I have to manually connect every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've got two postgresql installs one version 9.6 as a system install and one 10.4 as a user install.

The system install is on port 5432 which is the default port number, so there's something overriding the psql connection so that it finds the version 10.4.

There should be a psql somewhere that came with the 9.6 install.
if you run that one it should connect you to the 9.6.

if that was the enterprisedb installer it looks like

/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/psql

might be the one you need.

perhaps some mac-os guru can fill in the blanks like how to set the search path to find that psql first.

Comment: So it means I have to use the pgadmin version that is an older version instead of using the latest on both? It seems odd that both versions are out of sync where we have to use one older and one updated. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this. Thanks

Comment: you've got two different installers from different vendors, there's probably a way to install a new pgadmin or tell your existing one to use the new database, but you initially asked to make psql talk to the pg-admin one,,,